# Crosstool-NG missing dependency

Tags: macos, build, toolchain, crosstool-ng

I'm trying to set up a toolchain using `Crosstool-NG`. I'm using `Crosstool-NG 1.22.0` on `OS X 10.11.4`.

I installed using `homebrew`, so I'm unsure of why I'm missing dependencies. When I try to build, this is my output:

```
$ ct-ng build
[INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
[INFO ]  Build started 20160504.172530
[INFO ]  Building environment variables
[ERROR]  Missing: 'x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0-gcj' or 'x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0-gcj' or 'gcj' : either needed!
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_Abort[scripts/functions@329]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: CT_TestAndAbort[scripts/functions@351]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@458]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/usr/local/Cellar/crosstool-ng/1.22.0/share/doc/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng-1.22.0/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 0:01.00)
[00:02] / make: *** [build] Error 1
```

I can attach my .config file if needed, but I believe the error is before that.

I've already tried running:

```
$ brew install gcc --with-java
```

But the error still persists. I've been following a few tutorials online, mainly [this](http://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/cross-compiling-on-mac-osx-for-raspberry-pi/) one, so maybe there is an error with it. I've checked the `build.log` output and it is nearly identical to the shell output. Is there a known solution to this issue or am I forgetting a step somewhere?

Comment: can you actually invoke `gcj` by one of those names?